# Enables Master/Replica operations with spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, redis-cluster, spring-boot-starter

I'm using spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive and @SpringBootApplication annotation to auto configure redis connection. I have set up a redis cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves. I have the following config in the application.properties file

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes=master-node:6379,slave1-node:6379,slave2-node:6379
```

I want to configure it so that all writes go to master, and all reads go to slaves (slave preferred).

I found that it is using Lettuce driver under the hood. In order to achieve this, I need to add `.readFrom(SLAVE_PREFERRED)` into the `LettuceClientConfiguration`. Looked at the `org\springframework\boot\autoconfigure\data\redis\LettuceConnectionConfiguration.class`, I don't see a way to add this config. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer

```
  public LettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer lettuceClientConfigurationBuilderCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder.readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `readFrom` property is specific to **Lettuce** and it's not (or at least I couldn't find) supported by Spring Boot's auto-configuration. So, if you need to use it, you should configure **Lettuce** client explicitly in your application

For example:

```
@Bean
protected LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    
    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder()
            .readFrom(ReadFrom.REPLICA_PREFERRED)
            .build();
    
    RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration()
            .master(redisProperties.getSentinel().getMaster());
    
    redisProperties.getSentinel().getNodes().forEach(s -> sentinelConfig.sentinel(s.split(":")[0],Integer.valueOf(s.split(":")[1])));
    sentinelConfig.setPassword(RedisPassword.of(redisProperties.getPassword()));
    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig, clientConfig);
}
```

ReadFrom options:

1. MASTER: Setting to read from the upstream only.
2. MASTER_PREFERRED: Setting to read preferred from the upstream and fall back to a replica if the master is not available.
3. UPSTREAM: Setting to read from the upstream only.
4. UPSTREAM_PREFERRED: Setting to read preferred from the upstream and fall back to a replica if the upstream is not available.
5. REPLICA_PREFERRED: Setting to read preferred from replicas and fall back to upstream if no replica is available.
6. REPLICA: Setting to read from the replica only.
7. ANY: Setting to read from any node.